# nestjs/soap (node soap) request failed despite the request data tested good

Tags: node.js, soap, nestjs

I'm using nestjs-soap@3.0.1 to request SOAP endpoints, below is the sample code:

```
const now = new Date();

const request = {
    clientID: 'some_client_id',
    checkSum: 'the_check_sum_string',
    checkTime: null,
    syn: false,
    content: JSON.stringify({
        QUERY_PARAM: {
            START_DATE: format.asString('yyyy-MM-dd', new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDate() - 7
            )),
            END_DATE: format.asString('yyyy-MM-dd', now),
            START_INDEX: 0,
            IS_SYN: 1,
            STATUS: status
        }
    }),
    format: 'JSON'
};

// Consume the endpoint
let response = await this.laiwuClient.queryPurOrderAsync(request);
```

Then Server returns

```
faultcode: 500,
faultstring: 'Invalid XML',
detail: 'Error: Unquoted attribute value\nLine: 46\nColumn: 9\nChar: /',
```

But when I tried to dump the request data out and use Postman like clients to test it. Everything works quite fine.

It's so weird to me. I would appreciate if anybody can help me on this.

Thanks